Is there a way to find the eigenvalues of a matrix using character table?
I am studying applications of representation theory. I want to know if there is a procedure to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix using the character table of the Group acting on its linear space.
So, my group is $S_4$
and I was able to write my 12x12 matrix in terms of irreducible representations as $χ=χ_1+χ_3+2χ_4+χ_5$
. Now, $χ_1$
has character 1, so I should get a 1x1 matrix, $χ_3$
has character 2 so I should get a 2x2 matrix, $χ_4$
has multiplicity 2 and character 3, so I should get 2 3x3 matrices and $χ_5$
has character 3, so I should get a 3x3 matrices.
So, adding up the number of eigenvalues of all these smaller matrices, I get 1 + 2 + 2*3 + 3 = 12. But how do I find these smaller matrices? Can somebody explain it to me? Or provide some other references, where such type of problem is handled?
Edit: The matrix in question isn't the representation matrix of the group. So, there is a vector space $V \equiv \mathbb R^{12}$, on which $G(=S_4)$ acts. Let the basis of $V$ be $v_1, v_2, ... v_{12}$. Now as I have the character table of $G$, and there is a formula for projection operator, $\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G}\chi(g^{-1})g$. Using this, I was able to obtain 12 expressions for the 12 basis vectors, and that gave me a 12x12 matrix. Now in the text, the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the 12x12 matrices are obtained by finding subspaces of the dimensions of the characters.
The book is "Representations and Characters of Groups", by G James and M Liebeck. I am working on example 32.20.

Hello. Given a group $G$ with, say, a finite-dimensional representation $\rho$ of $G$, the character associated to $\rho$ is a complex-valued function on $G$, whose value at $g \in G$ is the trace of the matrix $\rho(g)$. Your questions are a bit vague. Rather than interpreting them literally, I will try to interpret them in the best way I can.

Given $g \in G$, let us say you are interested in finding the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $\rho(g)$, well, if you know that the character $\chi$ of $\rho$ is the sum of characters of irreducible representation of $G$, then you know that, after some work, you can write $\rho(g)$ as the direct sum of smaller sized matrices, and the problem becomes that of finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of these smaller-sized matrices.

If you are decomposing a character in the way you seem to be, you are not just dealing with a single matrix (unless you know about group determinants), you are dealing with all the matrices in a particular group. I think you need to explain more fully what the matrix (or matrices) you are looking at is.

For a special case that includes the symmetric group $S_n$, see https://msp.org/pjm/1989/140-2/pjm-v140-n2-p06-p.pdf (Stembridge).

@GeoffRobinson I have edited the question to include what my matrix is. I don't know how much of it is clear.

cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4896160/87355

I don't understand the question; but in general if you have a character table and you want to find eigenvalues, the extra information you need is the power maps. Namely, for each conjugacy class of element $g$ and each prime $p$ dividing the order of $g$, you need to know which conjugacy class contains the element $g^p$. The ATLAS gives this information for exactly this reason.
